# What is the culture code for neutral language, such as German(Neural)?

Tags: delphi, visual-c++, locale

I am using Delphi XE3, in this document http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Language_Culture_Names,_Codes,_and_ISO_Values, I can see the culture code for different German language, but there is no one for German(Neutral).

However, in Visual C++ 2008, when adding resource, there is a language called German(Neutral).

So, how can I find the code for German(Neutral)?